# jQuery algorithm scrolling speed

Tags: jquery, scroll

There are dwo divs **#leftPane** and **#rightPane**. #leftPane has position relative and browser set scrollbar acording to its height, meanwhile #rightPane has position: fixed and I add top: -value to it while scrolling, so we 'scroll' secont div with different speed. What I want to achieve is get something like scrollSpeedModifier according to 1. browser window height, 2 leftPane content height and 3 rightPane content height (2,3 content height might be different each time).

So while scrolling #leftPane - if content of #rightPane is bigger than #leftPane its top value grow faster than normal scrolling, but when #rightPane content height is smaller than #leftPanes top value grow slower than normal scroling.

This is the way I count the speed right now:

```
ar scrollSpeed = (rightPaneHeight) / browserHeight;
```

but it's wrong, sometimes we get to the middle of the #rightPane and when we change the 'browser' size (jfiddle window size) we might get till the end of #rightPane.

This is the code I end up so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/bVfcX/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok fixed,
http://jsfiddle.net/bVfcX/21/

the right algorithm is:

```
-$(window).scrollTop() * ((browserHeight - rightPaneHeight) / (browserHeight - leftPaneHeight));
```

Answer (score 0):

see this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bVfcX/16/)

1. `var    doc = $(window); // for get height of document`
2. `doc.scrollTop` is a function use `doc.scrollTop()`

give it a try.

Comment: It still doesn't scroll the second div to the 'END' and when you change the jfiddle window size it scrolls to different position each time.

Comment: so it's your algorithm! :) you should change the algorithm